# How to open a File on a specific route with React Router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Is there a way to automatically open a file with react router on a specific route?
What I already tried is 
redirecting to the file itself

```
<Route path="agb"><Redirect to="../../src/assets/pdf/agb.pdf"></Redirect></Route>
```

also I tried to load the file as a component with import but that didnt work as expected

```
import Agbs from "../../src/assets/pdf/agb.pdf"
<Route path="agb">{Agbs}</Route>
```

In this scenario I want to start to download my pdf when someone visits /agb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem on my own by the following way:

Since the redirect didnt work, I imported the PDF within the wanted page and opened it directly with the help of javascript

```
import agb from "../../../assets/pdf/agb.pdf";
/* later within the component */
componentWillMount() {
    window.open(agb, '_blank');
    browserHistory.push("/somewhereelse");
}
```

But I´m not 100% satisfied with this solution, I would really like to solve it somehow with the help of the router.